# Create multiple shortcuts of single app on Phone desktop using objective c from app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can you give a solution how to create programmatically multiple shortcut desktop icon app from Single App using objective C.When clicking on shortcut it will redirect to Main Application?

Comment: This is not possible without jailbreaking.

Comment: This is not possible welcome to iOS world :)